# How to create a Continues running background file upload in android?

Tags: android, file-upload, service, background-process, fileobserver

I am developing an android application that can upload images one by one of a specific folder to the server from background without interrupting the UI. What I implemented is a intentService calls from the launcher activity with the runtime permissions to read the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. I need to upload all the files in the folder and also need to upload new file that are created or moved to the folder. For that I created a file observer class, which I think is not working properly.

```
  public class DirectoryFileObserver extends FileObserver {
String aboslutePath = "";

public DirectoryFileObserver(String path) {
    super(path, FileObserver.ALL_EVENTS);
    aboslutePath = path;
    Log.i("watch path", path);
}

@Override
public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
    Log.i("FileObserver++", "File Created:" + path);
    File file = new File(aboslutePath + "/" + path);
    List<Skeem> mSkeemList = Skeem.find(Skeem.class, "file = ?", new String[]{file.getAbsolutePath()});
    if (mSkeemList.size() == 0) {
        Skeem mSkeem = new Skeem();
        mSkeem.setUsername(AppConstants.UserEmail);
        mSkeem.setFolderName(aboslutePath);
        mSkeem.setFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
        uploadService uploadService = new uploadService();
        uploadService.upload(mSkeem);

    }

    switch (event) {
        case FileObserver.ALL_EVENTS:
            Log.d("All", "Path" + path);
            break;
        case FileObserver.CREATE:
            Log.d("Create", "Path" + path);
            break;
    }


}
 }
```

Also created a broad cast receiver as follows to resume file upload when the net connection is retained

```
public class InternetConnector_Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public InternetConnector_Receiver() {
    }

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {

        boolean isVisible = BaseApplication
                .isActivityVisible();// Check if
        // activity
        // is
        // visible
        // or not
        Log.i("Activity is Visible ", "Is activity visible : " + isVisible);

        // If it is visible then trigger the task else do nothing
        if (isVisible == true) {
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager
                    .getActiveNetworkInfo();

            // Check internet connection and accrding to state change the
            // text of activity by calling method
            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {

                Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, uploadService.class);
                context.startService(serviceIntent);

            } else {

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

and in manifest

```
   <receiver
        android:name=".InternetConnector_Receiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- Intent filters for broadcast receiver -->
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

I add all the files to the database with a status false.

```
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
                        for (int n = 0; n < skeemList.size(); n++) {
                            Skeem skeem = skeemList.get(n);
                            for (int o = 0; o < files.length; o++) {
                                if (!(skeem.getFile().equalsIgnoreCase(files[o].getAbsolutePath()))) {
                                    if (!files[o].isDirectory()) {
                                        Skeem mSkeem = new Skeem();
                                        mSkeem.setFile(files[o].getAbsolutePath());
                                        mSkeem.setFolderName(directory.getName());
                                        mSkeem.setUsername(email);
                                        upload(mSkeem);
                                    } 
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Then I starts uploading the files with status false and update table with status true.
When I launch the application, the image upload starts successfully. But after some time it stops. Am I using correct Service to upload files from background? Is there any way to upload the contents of the folder? I have gone through so many sites and links. But I couldn't find the exact solution I needed. Please help me.

Answer (score 4):

With the new [Background Limitations](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#services) for Service execution you need to be very cautious with background services.
Instead of an IntentService I recommend you to use a [JobIntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService.html) as Google suggests. Pre-Oreo it acts as an IntentService, on (Post-)Oreo it uses Jobs to do background work. Remember to request `WAKE_LOCK` permission

Comment: I am developing only for Pre-Oreo. And what is it  WAKE_LOCk permission to be used?

Comment: JobIntentService needs the permission to keep your service running. So your compileSDK is not >= 26, is it?

Comment: Wakelock keeps the device running even when screen is locked

Comment: When the app is killed the upload process stops. What should I do to continue the process even after the app is killed?

Comment: Your service should continue running. Can you show us your UploadService class?
also: What is your compileSDK

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to use GitHub library -

https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service  2.3K stars Apr 2020

[image]

"
-Easily upload files (Multipart/Binary/FTP out of the box) in the background with progress indication notification

-upload files to a server with FTP, HTTP multipart/form-data or binary requests

-handle multiple concurrent uploads in the background, even if the device is idle (Doze mode)

-automatically retry failed uploads, with a configurable exponential backoff
possibility to automatically delete uploaded files when the upload is successful

**Apps and libraries powered by this library-**

-JIRA Cloud

-Quora

...

"